# SQL Server 2014 offset fetch optimize

Tags: sql-server-2014

This is my SQL Server query for pagination.

```
declare @PageNumber INT;
declare @PageSize INT;

set @PageNumber = 1600000;
set @PageSize = 10;

SELECT  
    q.Id, q.QuestionTitle,
    SUBSTRING(q.QuestionContent,0,200) as QuestionContent,
    q.QuestionVote, q.QuestionView,
    q.Tag1, q.Tag2, q.Tag3, q.Tag4, q.Tag5,
    q.CreatedDate,q.ModifiedDate
FROM 
    Question AS q 
ORDER BY 
    q.Id DESC
    OFFSET @PageNumber * @PageSize ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

When page number is low there is no problem. But when page number is high, then query takes about 15-25 seconds.

`Id` column is a clustered index. There are 18 million records in the table.

How can I speed up this query?

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2016 (14.0) and I experienced the same, consistent performance in subsequent calls when issuing static offset fetch. But when issuing offset fetch in dynamic query, each subsequent call is longer than previous :-( anybody who can help here?